# Domain migration with google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, entra-id, federated

We have set up user account synchronization with single sign-on feature between our Azure AD and Google Cloud by using UPN.
Recently we have purchased a domain to our company, want to change the primary domain. 
In the first phase we changed the mail address and now We’re evaluating how can we change UPN.

As the first step I'm going to Add new domain and switch to new primary domain in google cloud.

So after I change the UPN, will my account automatically change when I login under new UPN? Do we have any side effects such as separate user creation?